# If condition for .attr("stroke-dasharray", function (d) (...)} d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement stroke-dasharray for one line usinf if-else condition. But It's not working. Can someone have a look at it and tell what is wrong here ?

```
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", function (d) {
      if (d.type != "Step") return ('3, 3');
      else
      return null;
    })
```

I want to make the red line in solid and other in dashed.
[image]

Following is the data of red line of one point. Only the red line has "type": "Step".

```
{
"status": 1,
"resource_name": "Step 1",
"type": "Step",
"ld": [0, 0],
"pathway_name": "pathway1"
 },
```

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994199/d3-conditional-styling-of-edges) and tried to implement like this. But I am not getting desired result.

What I am not able to do right here ?

That's the full code:

```
document.getElementById("Pathway").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("my_dataviz").innerHTML = "";

  // dimensions and margins
  var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 210,
  };
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = 1410 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 620 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // create a clipping region
  svg
    .append("defs")
    .append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  d3.json("JSON_files/SDG_pathway.json").then(function (data1) {                      // Change file name here
    var groupData = d3.group(data1, (d) => d.pathway_name);

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range([0, width]);
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 1]).range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(0).tickSize(-height);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(0).tickSize(-width);

    var gX = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.top + height) + ")"
      )
      .call(xAxis);

    var gY = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(yAxis);

    var focus = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    const color = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .range(["#e41a1c", "#A0A0A0", "#4daf4a", "#984ea3"]);

    var points_g = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .classed("points_g", true);

    var label = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    var div = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    const mouseover = function (event, d) {
      div.style("opacity", 1);
    };

    const mousemove = function (event, d) {
      div
        .html(function (d1) {
          if (d.type != "learner")
            return `The resource name is ${d.resource_name}`;
          else return `This is ${d.name}`;
        })
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("left", event.pageX + 15 + "px")
        .style("top", event.pageY + 15 + "px");
    };

    const mouseleave = function (event, d) {
      div.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0);
    };

    var points = points_g.selectAll("point").data(data1);

    points = points
      .enter()
      .append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
        if (d.type == "video") return "Images/video.jpg";
        else if (d.type == "pdf") return "Images/pdf.png";
        else if (d.type == "Start") return "Images/Start.png";
        else if (d.type == "Destination") return "Images/Destination.png";
        else if (d.type == "none") return "Images/GreenDot.png";
        else if (d.type == "Step") return "Images/Flag.png";
        else if (d.type == "iiitb") return "Images/BlueDot.png";
        else if (d.type == "learner") return "Images/learner.png";
      })
      .attr("x", function (d) {
        return xScale(+d.ld[0]) - 10;
      })
      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return yScale(+d.ld[1]) - 10;
      })
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mousemove", mousemove)
      .on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

    label
      .selectAll(".text")
      .data(data1)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.resource_name;
      })
      .attr("x", function (d) {
        return xScale(+d.ld[0]) + 10;
      })
      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return yScale(+d.ld[1]) + 10;
      });

    var createSeries = function (name, data, color) {

      // create and customize the connector series
      var connectorSeries = map
        .connector(data)
        .name(name)
        .fill(color)
        .stroke({
          color: color,
          thickness: 2
        });

      // change the coloring of the connector line in the hovered state
      connectorSeries
        .hovered()
        .stroke('1.5 #212121')
        .fill('#212121');

      // configure the arrow marker
      connectorSeries
        .markers()
        .position('100%')
        .fill(color)
        .stroke({
          color: color
        })
        .size(8);

      // configure the arrow marker in the hovered state
      connectorSeries
        .hovered()
        .markers()
        .position('100%')
        .size(10)
        .fill('#212121')
        .stroke('2 #455a64');

      // set the labels for the source countries
      connectorSeries
        .labels()
        .enabled(true)
        .format(function () {
          return this.getData('from');
        });

      // set the thickness of the connector line based on the series
      if (name === 'More than 50,000') {
        connectorSeries.startSize(5).endSize(2);
      } else if (name === '40,000 to 50,000') {
        connectorSeries.startSize(3.5).endSize(1.5);
      } else if (name === '20,000 to 40,000') {
        connectorSeries.startSize(3).endSize(1);
      } else if (name === '16,000 to 20,000') {
        connectorSeries.startSize(2).endSize(0.5);
      } else {
        connectorSeries.startSize(1).endSize(0);
      }

      // configure the settings for the legend items
      connectorSeries
        .legendItem()
        .iconType('square')
        .iconFill(color)
        .iconStroke(false);

    };
    focus
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(groupData)
      .enter()
      .append("path")

      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", function (d) {
        if (d.type != "Step") return ('3, 3');
        else
          return null;
      })
        
      // .attr("stroke-dasharray", "4, 4")   //Dashed line


      .attr("stroke", function (d) {
        return color(d[0]);
      })

      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("d", function (d) {
        return d3
          .line()
          .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
          .x(function (d) {
            return xScale(+d.ld[0]);
          })
          .y(function (d) {
            return yScale(+d.ld[1]);
          })(d[1]);
      });


    var zoom = d3
      .zoom()
      .scaleExtent([0.5, 20])
      .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height],
      ])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .lower();

    svg.call(zoom).call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);

    function zoomed({ transform }) {
      var new_xScale = transform.rescaleX(xScale);
      var new_yScale = transform.rescaleY(yScale);

      gX.call(xAxis.scale(new_xScale));
      gY.call(yAxis.scale(new_yScale));

      points
        .data(data1)
        .attr("x", function (d) {
          return new_xScale(d.ld[0]) - 10;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          return new_yScale(d.ld[1]) - 10;
        })
        .attr("visibility", function (d) {
          return d.level > transform.k == 0 ? "visible" : "hidden";
        });

      label
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(data1)
        .attr("x", function (d) {
          return new_xScale(d.ld[0]) + 15;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          return new_yScale(d.ld[1]) + 15;
        })
        .attr("visibility", function (d) {
          return d.level > transform.k == 0 ? "visible" : "hidden";
        });

      focus.selectAll("path").attr("d", function (d) {
        return d3
          .line()
          .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
          .x(function (d) {
            return new_xScale(+d.ld[0]);
          })
          .y(function (d) {
            return new_yScale(+d.ld[1]);
          })(d[1]);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the full code for lines?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I posted full code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Try `.attr("stroke-dasharray", d => d.type === "Step" ? "none" : "3, 3")` Does it help?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky No, It's still the same. It still dashed all lines, including the red one, like in the above image.

Comment: print out the data you enter: `console.log(groupData)`. What do you get?

Comment: Your data binding is not correct! `groupData` is the result of `d3.group` and, hence, is a map where the values are **arrays** of your data, not individual data points! The array has no property `.type` which is the reason why your logic won't work. You worked around that issue when generating the path generators where you pass in the second element of those arrays like so: `})(d[1]);`. Obviously, this also is not what you wanted. You need to do a complete review of your binding of the grouped data.

Comment: It will be great if you could share a working codepen.